# How do I check if the letter in an numpy array is in a premium tile?

Tags: python

I have a project about scrabble using computer vision. The project is almost done but I am stuck in knowing if the letter is on a premium tile.

```
output_tile = [['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'S' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'L' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'I' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'C' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'E' 'A' 'G' 'L' 'E' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'P' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'P' 'E' 'A' 'K' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'L' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'E' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']]
```

This is the output that I got after using computer vision then using this

```
points_dictionary = {
            'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3,
            'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 4, 'G': 2,
            'H': 4, 'I': 1, 'J': 8, 'K': 5,
            'L': 1, 'M': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 1,
            'P': 3, 'Q': 10, 'R': 1, 'S': 1,
            'T': 1, 'U': 1, 'V': 4, 'W': 4, 'X': 8,
            'Y': 4, 'Z': 10, '#': 0, '0':3
        }
```

I can get the points of each tile. But the problem is that how can I know if the word for example eagle is on a premium tile? A premium tile looks like this [Scrabble board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBEEU.jpg) For they contain double,triple letter (multiply 2 or 3 to a specific letter) and double,triple word(multiply 2 and 3 to an entire word).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You appear to be missing a lot of commas in the value of `output_tile`.

Comment: Oh it is because i use numpy array and reshape it to 15 by 15

Comment: If your deadline is almost up, you are in trouble, as this would be a farily sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: Yea I know but I can at least try to do it. Please, can you show me a method on how to check if the letter is on a premium tile?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this: create  function that given a row and column, returns the type of square; create an additional board that stores premium tags instead of played letters, and pair the two lists together; or use a more complicated data structure that stores more than just a letter at each position.

Comment: Can you show how to do it please?